# Postgres TIMESTAMP query

Tags: postgresql

I'm using copy to import a csv file into postgres, one of the fields contains a time value in HH:MM:SS formate. I want to be able to set this to a TIMESTAMP field,  I've looked through lots of documents but I'm struggling to work out what field type to set it to. I see lots of reference to creating fields with timezones or not, a date etc, not really what I'm after. The ultimate aim is to create reports based on time intervals, e.g. all data between 00:00:00 and 06:30:00 etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A timestamp in postgres is date and a time combined. For times only use the type time or time with time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE table01
(
  rowid bigint NOT NULL,
  time_field time without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT table01_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rowid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

And here is an file example:

```
100,12:30:59
200,08:59:01
```

You can importe this last file to `table01` using `copy` command like this:

```
COPY table01 from 'c:/tmp/table01.txt' with csv
```

Considerning that the file named `table01.txt` located at : `c:/tmp/` folder.

Reference:
[copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)